# SQL: calculation on two columns with multiple group by statements

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a table which has the following columns:

- user_id - includes duplicates
- product_id - includes duplicates
- purchases - number of purchases of given product_id

My table looks somewhat like this:

```
   user_id  date  product_id  purchases
0        1     1           1          4
1        1     2           1          0
2        1     3           2          0
3        1     4           2          0
4        2     1           1          1
5        2     2           1          0
6        2     3           1          1
7        3     1           2          0
8        3     2           3          0
9        4     1           5          1
```

My goal is to calculate the following metric:

% of products that were purchased at least once, grouped by user

For example: user 1 had 2 products, one of them got purchased at least once, the other one did not get purchased at all. So the metric would be the number of products that got purchased at least once / number of all products per user: 1/2 * 100 = 50%

I have little SQL experience so I do not have any legitimate code that could be corrected.

My desired output would be like this:

```
   user_id  total_products  products_with_purchases  metric
0        1               2                        1     50%
1        2               1                        1    100%
2        3               2                        0      0%
3        4               1                        1    100%
```

I would appreciate seeing a good practice solution to this problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    user_id,
    count(distinct product_id) as total_products,
    count(distinct case when purchases > 0 then product_id end) as products_with_purchases,
    100.00 * count(distinct case when purchases > 0 then product_id end)
        / count(distinct product_id) as metric
from T as t
group by user_id
```

https://rextester.com/EDSY39439

Comment: Hello @shawnt00 , thank you for your reply. Can you please explain to me the logic behind the code for products_with_purchases? I am assuming this returns 0 when purchases are equal to 0, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Maciej The inner `case` actually evaluates to a `null` by default (not 0) which is always ignored by the `count()` aggregate function. Essentially it boils down to "if purchase is zero then ignore this product id." You could add `else null` if you prefer to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in one query but this is the type of situation where it is easier to understand with sub-queries -- sql optimizer should make it fast.

```
select 
  user_id, 
  total_products,
  products_with_purchase,
  (products_with_purchase / total_products) * 100 as metric
from (
  select  -- group by user to get totals
    user_id, 
    count(product_id) as total_products,
    sum(case when purchases > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as products_with_purchase
  from ( -- group by user and product and get purchase items
    SELECT user_id, product_id, sum(purchases) as purchases
    FROM table
    GROUP BY user_id, product_id
  ) X
  group by user_id
) X2
```

Answer (score 0):

I Am Mohit Sahni 
you can solve the above problem with the below SQL Code:

```
select 
user_id,
count(distinct product_id) as total_products,
sum(case when purchases = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as products_with_purchases,
((sum(case when purchases = 0 then 0 else 1 end))/count(distinct product_id))*100 as metric
from 
table
group by 
user_id
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question exactly how the `date` column factors in. Unfortunately your approach doesn't account for the fact that the same product can appear with multiple dates yet apparently should only be counted once.

Comment: So the date is not really a factor at this stage. The data is gathered everyday, appearing in separate rows, however I am interested in the total.